# grabbing data from $_POST when you don't know what you need to grab in advance

Tags: php, optimization, forms, post

This will make sense with an example:

You've got a recipe site, that tracks 3 datapoints:

- recipe name (salad, chowder, etc.)
- ingredients (tomato, potato, pork, etc.)
- ingredient volume (integers only, to keep our example simple)

On the first page of my `Recipe Editor` we have a form to list the required ingredients.

```
Recipe: salad
  REQUIRES
    __ tomato
    __ lettuce
    __ cheese
    __ schweddy balls
```

On the second page, we get a list of all required ingredients and input boxes to enter the required volumes:

```
Recipe: salad
Ingredient    Volume
 tomato         2
 lettuce        1
 cheese         1
```

(contrived, I know, but bear with me)

Now that second form's list of ingredients and `<input ... />` boxes are generated dynamically from the database depending on the recipe chosen for editing.

Each ingredient has a numeric ID, so your volume input would look like:

```
<input type="text" name="17" value="" /> // how many tomatoes?
```

Once you `SUBMIT`, you need to process the `$_POST` array and upload all the ingredients and volumes -- but you (or at least I) don't know in advance what will be in that `$_POST` array because each recipe calls for different ingredients == `$_POST[???]`

The super-kludge I thought of was putting all the ingredient IDs into a comma-separated string, stick that into a hidden input field, and the explode it during processing and use it as $_POST keys to pull out the values. This certainly works, but it makes me feel all dirty inside.

Is there a better approach to getting input values out of $_POST when you don't know your keys in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use foreach, since $_POST acts just like any other array:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    switch($key)
    {
        case 17:
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can also check for the presence of specific keys using isset():

```
if(isset($_POST['17'])) {
    // ...
}
```

And for the record: there's nothing wrong with comma-separated input fields. The best solution is the one that works. :)

Answer (score 2):

That's not an uncommon issue, and for the recipies the approach looks plausible. But there is an alternative approach, if you would be able to adapt the form generation logic:

```
<input type="number" name="volume[tomatos]" value="">
```

Or keep using IDs with `name="volume[17]"` or something alike.

Anyway I think this is easy to generate with AJAX/DHTML too, and PHP can deal better with an input array like `$_GET["volume"][...]` - which in some cases can also be more reliable than receiving an uncertain ID-list. (You would still need the `foreach` certainly.)

Comment: Interesting. I knew about using an array for the name with checkboxes, but wasn't aware that you could do it with any old input, or that you could define the array key within the HTML. That's a nifty trick!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    echo "This recipe includes $value of ingredient $key."
}
```

To get the list of ingredient IDs, extract it from the $_POST array:

```
$ingredientIDs = array_keys($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="17" value="" />
```

Assuming your form method is POST...

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    echo "We need $value of item $key";
}
```

Should get you headed in the right direction.